is this c++ code Undefined Behaviour. Calling a method with a null value for 'this'
class A {
  
public:
    A() { std::cout << "Constructor\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "Deconstructor\n"; }
    void hi() { std::cout << "hi"; }
};



int main() { 
    A *p = nullptr;
    p->hi();
    return 0;
}

Ie calling a class method that does not use any data from the class , but using a null pointer
msvc and gcc compile it without complaint, gcc with -fanalyze warns at compile time

In C++ this can never validly be nullptr. Yes, it is UB. And btw; compilers are not required to diagnose UB.

If you make hi a static function, then it isn't UB.  (But then you could call it as A::hi() rather than through the convenient affordance of p->hi()... even with a nullptr for the A*.)

@Eljay whether calling a static member function through a nullptr is UB or not is actually an open question - personally I tend to lean towards that it is UB - using A::hi() is subtly different.

@JesperJuhl   I'm with you on that.  Generally speaking, when language lawyers can't agree on whether something involves undefined behaviour or not, I will default to assuming it is - and modify code/design to deliberately (and as unambiguously as possible) avoid undefined behaviour.   I don't really want code breaking (even worse, breaking in undetectable or hard-to-detect manners) when porting between compilers because different compiler vendors/developers have different interpretations of what freedoms they have.

Using a dereferenced nullptr like you do in p->hi(); means your whole program is incorrect (the term is undefined behavior.  And this is a situation you should always avoid.

@Eljay It has now been clarified that the call has undefined behavior even if the member is static and by strict interpretation that was the case before recent defect reports as well. See my answer in the linked duplicate.

@JesperJuhl That has been clarified with recent defect reports. See my answer in the linked duplicate.

@Peter That has been clarified with recent defect reports. See my answer in the linked duplicate.

@user17732522 • Thank you for tracking that down!  pm100 • Thank you for the question!
